# Собственная страница для ошибки 401

Tags: .htaccess, apache

У меня есть `.htaccess` файл с авторизацией в админку:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin Panel"
AuthUserFile C://OpenServer/domains/users/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Если нажать "Отмена" в авторизации, то на другой странице он выведет:

```
Authentication required!
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL 
"/admin/". You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), 
or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
```

и т.д. И ниже **ошибка 401**.
Вопрос: можно ли как-то отредактировать эту страницу? Например, через css или написать другой текст?

Comment: Как-то так? `ErrorDocument 401 путь/401.php`. Там измените под себя.. Но вот не знаю, как вызвать эту 401)

Answer (score 2):

создаете файл `401.html` с необходимым вам текстом и даже дизайном, затем в `.htaccess` добавляете строку `ErrorDocument 401 /401.html` - все готово

Comment: теперь выводит ошибку 500 server error

Comment: @AlievA., обратите внимание, у отвечающего пробел лишний перед 401.html, а сам файл должен существовать в корневой папке сайта.

Comment: ошибка 500 исчезла, но страница 401.html не отразилась, выводит почти тоже самое, только без ошибки 401 и еще

Comment: Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @AlievA., не забудьте выставить права доступа на файл. У вас нет прав на его просмотр сейчас.

Comment: и как это сделать?

Comment: установить права доступа 644, или -rw-rw-r--

Comment: смотря какой файл-менеджер вы используете для подключения к серверу, или ssh-клиент

Comment: @VenZell - там нет пробела, это отступ выделения кода

Comment: @iodev, посмотрите правку. Я уже удалил из ответа пробел лишний.

Comment: @VenZell, понял, спасибо. Еще не свыкся с функционалом.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку решил. Просто в `.htaccess` вместо файла написал `html` код

```
ErrorDocument 401 "<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><h1>Ошибка авторизации</h1></body></html>"
```